# sudo equivalent in systemd

Tags: linux, shell-script, systemd, sudo, pkexec

how to force "machinectl shell" or systemd-run to ask for password in terminal instead of dialog window?

I can run a command as root using:

```
machinectl shell --uid=root --setenv='DISPLAY=:1.0' --setenv=SHELL=/bin/bash .host /bin/bash -lc 'startxfce4'
```

but it ask for the password using the dialog window
[image]

I want to have the same behavior of sudo (sudo ask for the password using the terminal so I can script it easily)

on way I found is using ssh like that:

```
ssh -t MyActualNormalUser@localhost
```

then run the same command as above:

```
machinectl shell --uid=root --setenv='DISPLAY=:1.0' --setenv=SHELL=/bin/bash .host /bin/bash -lc 'thunar'
```

now machinectl ask for the password using the terminal instead of the GUI dialog window!
[image]

How can I achieve the same result without using ssh? is it possible to force machinectl/pkexec to ask for the password in the terminal?

<sub>why not use sudo? sudo do not create a new session for the command I run , machinectl run a totally separated session which make life in scripting easier. and as I read machinectl/pkexec are the su/sudo replace if I m not wrong...</sub>

Comment: I'm not a systemd user, but does it work if you unset DISPLAY variable?

Comment: @Danh no, it always ask for the password using the gui

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Run a command as another user

to run something as another user we have different methods:

- **machinectl**: this create a separate session
- **ssh**: this create a separate session
- **systemd-run**: this do not create a separate session, but create a separated service unit that can be controlled too like the session.
  for example when I run `loginctl session-status` I get this error: `Could not get properties: Caller does not belong to any known session` , because of no session ID.
- **pkexec**: this do not create a separate session
- **sudo**: this do not create a separate session

## How to pass the password in terminal (not gui)

we can use:

- **pkexec**: this need pkttyagent
- **machinectl**: this ask for password using gui , to use tty for pass we need pkexec/sudo or ssh
- **systemd-run**: this ask for password using gui , to use tty for pass we need pkexec/sudo or ssh
- **sudo**: sudo have to be replaced by pkexec
- **ssh**: this will need root password or we need to use pkexec/sudo or ssh user@localhost

## Conclusion:

only machinectl and ssh gave me a separated session , systemd-run is not bad too but it is for scripts not for creating sessions.

and to gain root we can use pkexec

- **machinectl**

```
    timeout 3s sshpass -e pkttyagent -p $(echo $$) &
    pkexec machinectl shell --uid=root --setenv="DISPLAY=:1.0" --setenv=SHELL=/bin/bash .host /bin/bash -lc "startxfce4"
```

- **ssh**

```
    timeout 3s sshpass -e pkttyagent -p $(echo $$) &
    pkexec ssh -t root@localhost  "bash -lc  'export DISPLAY=:1.0 ; startxfce4'"
```

- **systemd-run**

```bsh
    timeout 3s sshpass -e pkttyagent -p $(echo $$) &
    pkexec systemd-run --pty --pipe --wait --collect --service-type=exec --uid=root bash -lc "export DISPLAY=:1.0 ; export SHELL=/bin/bash ; startxfce4"
```

pkttyagent : is needed to force pkexec to ask for the password using the terminal instead of the dialogue Gui

timeout 3s : is needed because pkttyagent will not die alone.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

You can use `systemd-ask-password` to assign a password to a bash variable.

**Example**

```
password=$(systemd-ask-password --echo "machinectl password: ")
machinectl login {{ user }} $password
machinectl shell {{ your command }}
```

### Solution 2

As root user, you can use `machinectl --no-ask-password`.
From the documentation:

> --no-ask-password
>
> Do not query the user for authentication for privileged operations.

### References

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-ask-password.html
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machinectl.html

Comment: sorry but both solutions are not working, I think you did not understand my problem: I want to force machinectl to ask for the password using the terminal not the gui dialogue, like when we use sudo + command... I found a solution (using pkexec + pkttyagent) which seems the canonical method:  `sshpass -p Mypassword pkttyagent -p $(echo $$) | pkexec machinectl shell --uid=root --setenv="DISPLAY=:1.0" --setenv=SHELL=/bin/bash .host /bin/bash --login -c startxfce4`

Comment: @BadrElmers, is the command `sudo machinectl --no-ask-password shell --uid=root --setenv='DISPLAY=:1.0' --setenv=SHELL=/bin/bash .host /bin/bash -lc 'thunar'` combining `sudo` and the flag `--no-ask-password` answering you problem?

Comment: no, same problem, I want to avoid [sudo](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/453/what-about-sudo-makes-it-less-secure-than-pkexec) .
and `--no-ask-password` only force machinectl to not ask for a password.

Comment: Following you link, I understand that you are using PolicyKit. Is it an option for you to bypass the password check?

Comment: yes I m attempting to change my sudo things to pkexec (PolicyKit) . bypass the password check is not a solution because hardening security is my objective not the inverse...thanks

Comment: Your problem seems linked to the agent used. Is the following helping you ? 
`machinectl shell --uid=root --setenv='DISPLAY=:1.0' --setenv=SHELL=/bin/bash .host /bin/bash -lc 'startxfce4'; pkttyagent --process $(pgreg machinectl)`

Comment: no , it ask for password using gui dialogue, the solution that works is this `sshpass -p Mypassword pkttyagent -p $(echo $$) | pkexec machinectl shell --uid=root --setenv="DISPLAY=:1.0" --setenv=SHELL=/bin/bash .host /bin/bash --login -c startxfce4`

Comment: Alright, I let you answer you own question and I will upvote :).

Comment: thank you for your help