# Why isn't a systemd user session started by `su`?

Tags: systemd, pam, su, logind

When I use ssh to log in to the root user on my server, an entry `0` is created in `/var/run/user` because `pam_systemd` tells `systemd-logind` to do this. This is an indicator that a user session has been started for uid 0.

Then, when I run `su jack`, I still only see the `0` entry in `/var/run/user`; no entry has been made for this session.

However, `journalctl` shows that a pam session was opened, and `/etc/pam.d/su` includes `common-session`, which adds `session optional pam_systemd.so`. So I think that a user session should have been created.

How can I make `su` create a user session?

If it's relevant, I'm on Debian 11.

Comment: Why do you need a full session?  Have you tried `su - jack` ?

Comment: I'm trying to get a full session so that `systemctl --user` works. `su - jack` didn't work either :(

Comment: su is intended to allow for access with alternate credentials within another session.  If you want a new session, you have to log in instead.

Comment: How can I log in from within a running session?

Comment: You can't.  You have to start a new session, possibly on another terminal or through the network.

Comment: Ahh so probably what's happening is logind explicitly refuses to launch a new session from within a running one.

Comment: It's more like, it doesn't make sense to have a session inside another session, and there are no provisions within logind to create a session outside of the normal methods of logging in.  Logind doesn't "refuse"; you just have not asked it correctly.

Comment: I use `loginctl enable-linger` to make the user manager of a user start regardless of whether it has a session. When I also have some user service that starts e.g. tmux. Then I'll be able to `systemctl --user` if I attach to the same tmux server (by setting `TMUX_TMPDIR`) after `su -`.

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/545328/117549

Comment: Also relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/615964/272848

Comment: This question isn't about sudo or su, it's about systemd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PAM module does not create a session if the current process is already a member of an existing session. I found the following workaround to create a session from an existing session:

```
systemd-run --system --scope \
    su -l
```

Basically you run `su -l` inside a system level scope, this is not part of the current user session and so the PAM module will create a session for the `su -l` process. Once the process has been moved to the session the temporary scope is empty and will be removed.

The only issue is that your current user must have the permission to create scopes at system level and you have to authenticate twice, once for the current user to authenticate creation of the scope and then again as the user for whom you want to create a session.